# Having to send SIGINT multiple times for Puppeteer script to close

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, readline

I'm new to node.js so there's probably something I'm not understanding about async functions. I'm having a minor issue where I have to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> at least two times before SIGINT is registered. I'd expect to only have to do it once.

In my script, I'm catching SIGINT and doing some cleanup but it still happens without it so I'm not sure if this is affecting it. I do see a log message once it is registered. The following is not my complete code since it's too long.

```
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const userAgent = require('user-agents');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

let browser;
let page;

function sigintHandler() {
    console.log("Handling interrupt.");
    process.exit();
}

process.on('SIGINT', sigintHandler); // Register sigint handler

(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            defaultViewport: null,
            args: ['--disable-features=site-per-process',
                   '--window-size=1920,1080']
        });
    page = (await browser.pages())[0];
})();
```

Does anyone know if this is normal behavior? If not how could I fix this?

Comment: Do you see the "Handling interrupt." log at all?

Comment: I do once it actually registers

Comment: Maybe `await browser.close()` throws and `process.exit()` is not being called then? Have you tried whether a second `console.log()` prints something after `await browser.close()` as well?

Comment: Oh it might since It doesn't print after so I removed `await browser.close()` but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After commenting out a ton of code and adding it back in I realized that the problem was caused by readline catching SIGINT. I was using this for prompting the user. Replacing `proccess.on` with `rl.on` fixed it.